# Object reference not set to an instance error for ebay finding api

Tags: c#-4.0, object-reference

I 'm developing an application which will search for a product & retrieve all details like sellerInfo,shippingInfo,price,etc...However ,I'm getting error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" while retrieving seller username & shippingInfo with the following syntax: This is for shipping cost:

```
 SearchItem[] items = response.searchResult.item;
double shippingcost=items[i].shippingInfo.shippingServiceCost.Value.
```

This is for sellerInfo:

```
string sellerInfo = items[i].sellerInfo.sellerUserName;
```

Please help,The control is going directly to catch block & raising exception. I tried checking for the null using if condition but no success its raising exception.

Comment: please post complete code! so we can look into the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the `null` Values as:

```
if(somval!=null && somval!=DBNULL.Value)
{
  ///do stuff
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself.What I did is I created an Object of shipping info like the above:

```
string selleruname; 
double shippingcost;
SellerInfo si = new SellerInfo();
ShippingInfo ship = new ShippingInfo();
SearchItem[] items = response.searchResult.item;




                    si = items[i].sellerInfo;
                    if (si == null)
                    {
                       selleruname = "Not Present";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         selleruname=si.sellerUserName;
                    }
                    ship = items[i].shippingInfo;
                    if (ship.shippingServiceCost == null)
                    {
                        shippingcost = 0.0;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        shippingcost = ship.shippingServiceCost.Value;
                    }
```

Thanks to all for reply & your efforts.

Regards
Rishiraj M Shengule
rishiraj.shengule@ymail.com